# Rownumber() is skipping numbers in query results

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I'm using a query to collect records from 5 tables, exclude records from a 6th table, and then give the results an incremental number using row_number(). But when I look through the results, some numbers are getting skipped (9, 12, 17). There doesn't seem to be any pattern to which row numbers are missing.

```
select Email as EmailAddress, FirstName, row_number() over (order by "Date") as Increment, "Date" from (
    select Email, FirstName, "Date" from (
        select Email, SUBSTRING(full_name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', full_name, 0)) AS FirstName, "Date Collected" as "Date" from [Table 1]
        where "Date Collected" < DateAdd(d, -14, getDate())
        union
        select Email, Null as FirstName, "Request Date" as "Date" from [Table 2]
        where "Request Date" < DateAdd(d, -14, getDate())
        union
        select Email, SUBSTRING(full_name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', full_name, 0)) AS FirstName, "Date Collected" as "Date" from [Table 3]
        where "Date Collected" < DateAdd(d, -14, getDate())
        union
        select Email, Null as FirstName, "Request Date" as "Date" from [Table 4]
        where "Request Date" < DateAdd(d, -14, getDate())
        union
        select Email, SUBSTRING(full_name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', full_name, 0)) AS FirstName, "Date Collected" as "Date" from [Table 5]
        where "Date Collected" < DateAdd(d, -14, getDate())
    ) z
    left join [Excluded Table] m on m.MemberPrimaryEmailAddress = z.Email
    where m.MemberPrimaryEmailAddress is null
) y
```

Edit: I have tried removing the left join, and it did not solve the row_number() issue.

Comment: Is this an overwrite query and do you have a PK field?

Comment: Yes and yes, the EmailAddress is the primary key.

Comment: I imagine you are losing rows due to overwrite tossing rows to honor the PK

Comment: Wouldn't my query result in an error saying there's a violation of the primary key rule?

Comment: Because that’s how an overwrite query works. It keeps 1 row and discards the rest

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for explaining.